# How to pull latest changes from Vercel commerce repo into my repo

Tags: git, next.js, bigcommerce, headless, vercel

A year before I had created a webshop with Vercel-Commerce demo. It's based on headless bigcommerce and NextJs. deployment is on Vercel and I had used `deploy demo` click from Vercel website.
After this, I made changes and completed my project.
Now After a year, Vercel has done a lot of changes in their demo, I want to sync up and pull the latest changes from their repo to my repo.

How can I do this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pull the latest changes from the Vercel repo into your repo, you'll need to do this from GitHub using the **Fetch upstream ▸ Fetch and merge** button: [image: Fetch upstream button]

Comment: Hi Thanks, @Jordan , I got the idea, But now the problem is while setting up the project, Vercel cloned a new repo into my login, hence it's not a fork of the original repo, would I still be able to pull changes from upstream anyhow?

Comment: @Furquan If the vercel repo cloned to your repository isn't a fork, then you won't be able to fetch the upstream as far as I know. Your best bet would be to create your own fork and use that one and if you need to deploy it then you should use the vercel CLI